# Trying to call out multiple objects from a JSON array displayed by radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, radio-button

I am making a website. What it's trying to display is schedules for sports teams. I have a JSON file for each team. I want to be able to click on a radio button from a certain team to have it display certain pieces of information within the JSON file in another div.

So I will post an example of one team.
Radio button:

```
<tr><td><label>
<input type="radio" name="teamShow" value="cCubs">Chicago Cubs
</label></td></tr>
```

The JQuery:

```
$("input[name='teamShow']").change(function() {
    selected = $('input[name=teamShow]:checked' ).val();
    console.log(selected);
    if (selected == "cCubs") { 
            $('#markerMessage7').html(
            $.getJSON( "ChicagoCSked.json", function( data ) {
                $.each(data, function(i, entry) {
                    displayData = data.ccJSON.SUBJECT[0];})
            })
            )
        }
    })
```

The body:

```
<div id ="markerMessage7">-</div>
```

The JSON (only one piece of array):

```
ccJSON =[
{
"START_DATE":"02/27/14",
"START_TIME":"02:05 PM",
"START_TIME_ET":"03:05 PM",
"SUBJECT":"D-backs at Cubs",
"LOCATION":"Cubs Park",
"DESCRIPTION":"",
"END_DATE":"02/27/14",
"END_DATE_ET":"02/27/14",
"END_TIME":"05:05 PM",
"END_TIME_ET":"06:05 PM",
"REMINDER_OFF":"FALSE",
"REMINDER_ON":"TRUE",
"REMINDER_DATE":"02/27/14",
"REMINDER_TIME":"01:05 PM",
"REMINDER_TIME_ET":"02:05 PM",
"SHOWTIMEAS_FREE":"FREE",
"SHOWTIMEAS_BUSY":"BUSY"
},
```

I can't seem to get it to write anything. I would like it to have the start date, subject, and start time. I was working solely on getting subject to work, that's why it's the only thing in my code.

Comment: Did you check my fiddle?  That gives an example of how to get information in another div.   http://jsfiddle.net/g98Em/

Comment: Yes I did. But the "subject" part of my json still didn't load

Answer (score 1):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/oQiJijAs/2/edit) (<sub>[and this JSON page example](http://jsbin.com/oHuzAza/3/edit)</sub>)

I would suggest you to have a slightly different JSON structure:

```
{
  "cCubs" : {
    "START_DATE":"02/27/14",
    "START_TIME":"02:05 PM",
    "START_TIME_ET":"03:05 PM",
    "SUBJECT":"D-backs at Cubs",
    "LOCATION":"Cubs Park"
  },
  "Something" : {
    "START_DATE":"02/29/14",
    "START_TIME":"04:00 PM",
    "START_TIME_ET":"05:05 PM",
    "SUBJECT":"Something subject",
    "LOCATION":"Something Park"
   }
}
```

having this you can have radio buttons like:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="teamShow" value="cCubs">
    Chicago Cubs
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="teamShow" value="Something">
    Something
</label>
```

and this trivial JS:

```
$("input[name='teamShow']").change(function() {

    var selected = $('input[name=teamShow]:checked').val();
    var displayData = "";

    $.getJSON( "allTeamsData.json", function( data ) {        
        displayData = data[selected].SUBJECT;
        $('#markerMessage7').html( displayData );        
    });

});
```

Comment: Just tried it and didn't even get an alert nor did I get the game to come up.

Comment: @user3109532 ok, edited with another idea. I would kindly use it.
Provided also the working demo and a JSON page example. Hope I don't need to mention that you cannot just copy-paste it before doing your changes like `allTeamsData.json` ...etc

Comment: My JSON is 3800 lines of code relating to the schedule of the team. So less JSON reformatting, the better. 

Each {} is a game. I want it to loop through all `"START_DATE"`,`"START_TIME"`,and `"SUBJECT"` and display them all. 

And yes, I would make changes accordingly to the code for each team.

Comment: @user3109532 You can re-format your JSON with a couple of JS lines, and copy-paste the tree again into the same file... Well, anyway, at least I hope this examples gave you an idea how to do it... Hopefully you'll be able to do it your self now. If you have questions feel free to ask.